# Create table field in oracle with default subquery value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, create-table

```
SQL> select * from table1;

PRICES
----------
   300
   520
   220
   820
   350
   790
   247

CREATE TABLE2 (DESCRIPT VARCHAR2(10), TOTALPRICES NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 
                                                 (SELECT SUM(PRICES) FROM TABLE1);
```

I want something like that, when I

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES ('TOTAL OF DAY');     
SELECT * FROM TABLE2;
```

I want that to display :

```
 DESCRIPT        TOTALPRICES
--------------   -----------
 TOTAL OF DAY       3247
```

Comment: Please don't shout, and make some more effort formatting your question. Be nice to the people you are asking for help!

Comment: You cannot default a value that requires a calculation from some other table - it just isn't feasible. You can insert the calculated value - but when is this to be done? at midnight? at "close of business"? (what is that for you?)

Comment: I would recommend you to use Views for such cases instead of using another table.

Comment: I just want to create a table2 and inside that table2 create a field that receive or insert automatically the value that return this query "SELECT SUM(PRICES) FROM TABLE1"  when i insert something in the other field of the same table2, i dont want to do something like that; INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('some string here', SELECT SUM(prices) FROM table1);

Comment: @AndyRodriguezJimenez Why don't you want to have the `select sum...` in the insert statement? That is exactly where it should go, IMHO. Better yet, create a stored procedure that accepts parameters for the other columns, and use that to do the insert.

Comment: Because i just need to insert in the column1 and them the column2 should be inserted automatically by the SUM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to implement this and one among them is to use a row level `Trigger`.

But, I would recommend you to use a `View` because it's not always worth having a table just to store values that can be generated from another table.

**Creating a View**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_table1 as select  'TOTAL OF DAY' as DESCRIPT
, SUM(prices)  as TOTALPRICES
FROM Table1;
```

This allows you to simply query the view and the values will be generated from the underlying tables.

```
   select * from v_table1;
```

If you feel that the underlying query of the view may be slow, you may convert it into a Materialised View.

**Trigger** should be your last option.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_table2  BEFORE INSERT ON Table2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

 SELECT SUM(PRICES) INTO :NEW.TOTALPRICES FROM Table1;

END;
/
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b7f4bb915e1d6b9f419f7727f779ee1b)